# How to prevent Black from adding a line break after union(`|`) type annotations

Tags: python, python-black

Black formats my code to:

```
operators: list[str]
| None = Query(
    default=None,
    description="operators",
),
```

but I want it to be formatted as:

```
operators: list[str] | None = Query(
    default=None,
    description="operators",
),
```

Black formatter adds a line break after the `| None` part in the code above. I'm curious why a line break occurs after the `|` operator. I'd like to know how to control or prevent such line breaks after the `|` operator in Black.

Additionally, I'm wondering if there are any options to change or rewrite the code so that Black doesn't introduce line breaks after the `|` operator in type hints.

I checked the black docs, but couldn't find it.

Comment: It might be helpful to [edit] in the complete function signature (without the function body) and the version of Black you are using. That said, Black is a very opinionated formatter, with very few configuration options.

Comment: Also, what is `Query`? Is that from FastAPI by any chance? I have code similar to that and I never encounter this line break with Black, but it maybe because I'm using the [Annotated syntax for FastAPI query params](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/?h=annotated#import-query-and-annotated).

Comment: @GinoMempin thanks. The observed behavior was found only in FastAPI's endpoints while checking the code.

Comment: Well, I don't have an answer for Black though, but if it's FastAPI code, as I mentioned you can try using the `Annotated` syntax. It doesn't quite match what you want, but at least it doesn't break on `|`: see example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVpdI.png.

Comment: @GinoMempin After further investigation, I discovered that the issue wasn't specific to FastAPI. It occurs similarly in Python when specifying the type of a method parameter using '|' and retrieving the default value from another method. Thank you.
`def datetime_to_string(
    target_time: datetime | None, format: str = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
) -> str:
    return target_time.strftime(format) if target_time else None


def get_func(
    _datetime_str: str
    | None = datetime_to_string(
        target_time=datetime.now(), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
    ),
):
    print(_datetime_str)`

Comment: The `|` operator for type annotation was introduced in 3.10. You likely have an outdated version of black.

Comment: @blhsing thank you. I am using the latest version (23.12.1).